# Alternatives to .htaccess RewriteEngine?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a site that I'm building at the moment, and I just noticed that, while www.mysite.com.au works fine, mysite.com.au still points to the crazydomains.com.au holding page, even though I only bought a domain name off them, and am actually hosting it on PythonAnywhere. So I created a .htaccess file to add "www." to the front of urls:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mysite.com.au%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

However, mysite.com.au now gets "Server Not Found" as a response (www.mysite.com.au still works fine).

I've checked to make sure the CNAME record in CrazyDomains is correct, and to the best of my knowledge it is. PythonAnywhere doesn't officially support .htaccess files, so it might be that? Is there an obvious thing that I'm missing? Are there any alternatives to .htaccess that would give me the same result?

Comment: If your hosting does not support .htaccess then it is defiantly that causing the problem. (I think it's mad that some hosting services do not provide .htaccess)

Comment: Do you have `mysite.com.au` defined as a `ServerAlias`?

Comment: @OlafDietsche Not that I know of, how would I achieve this?

Comment: It depends, if you have access to the main or virtual host config. There you have `ServerName` defined and you can add `ServerAlias` too. Maybe there's a web interface, where you can configure such things. This is only a thought, not sure if it helps.

Comment: the easiest would be to set up a permanent redirect from mysite.com.au to www.mysite.com.au- this should be something you can just tweak from within crazydomains